# Gradle sync failed after restarting android studio, Cannot convert string value 'ML_MODEL_BINDING'

Tags: android, gradle

I did 'Invalidate Caches/Restart' in Android studio and then I got this error while syncing gradle.

> Cannot convert string value 'ML_MODEL_BINDING' to an enum value of type 'com.android.builder.model.AndroidGradlePluginProjectFlags$BooleanFlag' (valid case insensitive values: APPLICATION_R_CLASS_CONSTANT_IDS, TEST_R_CLASS_CONSTANT_IDS, TRANSITIVE_R_CLASS, JETPACK_COMPOSE)

I am using gradle 4.1.0-alpha05

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0-alpha05'
```

I have tried clean project, rebuild project, deleted the build files and restarted Android Studio. Nothing worked

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your Android Studio version?

Comment: Android Studio 4.1 canary 5

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Had the same problem on IntelliJ 2020.1.3 .

What worked for me was updating gradle versions to the highest available:

in file **build.gradle** (project)

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0-beta03'
```

in file **gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

Comment: Thanks!  This fixes my issue on Intellij

Answer (score 6):

I'm facing the same issue on my KMP project.

The problem is on `AndroidGradlePluginProjectFlags.java` they add `JETPACK_COMPOSE` and `ML_MODEL_BINDING` to the `BooleanFlag` enum, so probably somewhere in the build tools they are trying to access it but the plugin implementation does not have it yet.

I tried to use the Android Studio 4.1 Canary 6 and it works to my project, hopefully, it works to your need too.

As a reference, there is an issue on IntelliJ support site [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360008037240-Gradle-doesn-t-work-anymore-after-IDEA-update-Cannot-convert-string-value-JETPACK-COMPOSE-?page=1#community_comment_360001590699).

Answer (score 3):

Downgrading to `4.1.0-alpha02` got rid of the error.

Using Android Studio 4.1 Canary 2.